# Go vendoring on App Engine Standard

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

I know this topic has been referenced a few times already. Unfortunately I still wasn't able to find a working solution for my use case.

I can't seem to get vendoring working for my Go application on App Engine Standard. I'm using [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep) for vendoring.

I'm building a GraphQL API and here is my folder structure:

```
/GOPATH
└──/src
   └──/acme
      ├──/app
      |   ├── app.yaml
      |   └── app.go
      ├──/src
      |   ├── /mutations/
      |   ├── /queries/
      |   └── /types/
      └──/vendor/
```

Running `goapp serve app/app.yaml` on Cloud Shell fails with

```
INFO     2018-05-14 15:42:08,386 devappserver2.py:764] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2018-05-14 15:42:08,471 api_server.py:268] Starting API server at: http://0.0.0.0:47213
INFO     2018-05-14 15:42:08,600 dispatcher.py:199] Starting module "default" running at: http://0.0.0.0:8080
INFO     2018-05-14 15:42:08,601 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://0.0.0.0:8000
ERROR    2018-05-14 15:42:13,983 go_runtime.py:181] Failed to build Go application: (Executed command: /google/go_appengine/goroot/bin/go-app-builder -app_base /home/xxx/gopath/src/acme/app -arch 6 -dynamic -goroot /google/go_appengine/goroot -gopath /home/xxx/gopath:/google/gopath -nobuild_files ^^$ -incremental_rebuild -unsafe -binary_name _go_app -extra_imports appengine_internal/init -work_dir /tmp/tmpbt8DA2appengine-go-bin -gcflags -I,/google/go_appengine/goroot/pkg/linux_amd64_appengine -ldflags -L,/google/go_appengine/goroot/pkg/linux_amd64_appengine app.go)
/home/xxx/gopath/src/acme/vendor/github.com/graphql-go/graphql/definition.go:4: can't find import: "context"

2018/05/14 15:42:09 Can't find package "context" in $GOPATH: cannot find package "context" in any of:
        /home/xxx/gopath/src/acme/vendor/context (vendor tree)
        /google/go_appengine/goroot/src/context (from $GOROOT)
        /home/xxx/gopath/src/context (from $GOPATH)
        /google/gopath/src/context
```

Looks like the problem might be that one vendor is not using a full dependency name for "context".
(EDIT: probably not the case though since I’m using 1.8)

Has anyone ever managed to successfully deploy on App Engine Standard using vendoring? Been pulling my hair all day on this.

Comment: "context" is the full dependency name, because it's in the standard library, since Go 1.7. Which version of Go are you using?

Comment: Fait enough, then the problem is elsewhere. I’m using 1.8

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else struggles with this, this is the approach I've taken that seems to work for me.

Directory structure looks like this:

```
/GOPATH
├──/appengine
|  ├──/.git/
|  ├──/project1
|  |  ├── app.yaml
|  |  └── app.go
|  └──/project2
|     ├── app.yaml
|     └── app.go
└──/src
   ├──/project1
   |  ├──/.git/
   |  ├──/mutations/
   |  ├──/queries/
   |  ├──/types/
   |  ├──/vendor/
   |  └──/main.go
   └──/project2
      ├──/.git/
      ├──/foo/
      ├──/bar/
      ├──/vendor/
      └──/main.go
```

Each **app.go** file below the appengine folder contains:

```
package projectX

import "projectX"

func init() {
    projectX.Run()
}
```

Each **main.go** file below src/projectX contains:

```
package projectX

import (
    // Import whatever you need
    "google.golang.org/appengine"
)

func Run() {
    // Do whatever you need
    appengine.Main()
}
```

Seems that having the folder that contains **app.yaml** outside of $GOPATH/src is indeed necessary.

This is also not ideal for version control if you need to have each project versioned under their own git repo as opposed to having one monolyth repo. I solved this by versioning each project AND versioning the appengine folder as well separately.

Comment: You can have app.yaml under GOPATH /src it just have to be in a separate folder. All imports should ne in GOPATH and outisde of folder with app.yaml. For example I have lke this: `/GOPATH/src/project1/root` & `/GOPATH/src/project1/app` where app imported from the root.

Comment: And vendoring was promised with support of Go 1.10 - means not going happen anytime soon as even 1.9 is currently just in beta.

Comment: Thanks, that looks very similar to what I had before (check OP). Maybe I could have investigated a bit more. At the moment I am quite happy with the alternative I have in place.

Answer (score 1):

I was having issues with, spent ages looking around trying to figure out why it wasn't working. This answer is a little late but hopefully will be useful for anyone else who has this issue.

I updated to use Go 1.11 which I thought wasn't supported (found one of the GCP examples on github using it [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/master/appengine/go11x/helloworld))

Set `runtime: go111` in `app.yaml` and it will support vendoring and give you a link to a proper build log.

Now my directory structure is as follows.

`/GOPATH
└──/src
   ├──/project1
   |  ├──/.git/
   |  ├──/whateverCode/
   |  ├──/vendor/
   |  └──/main.go
   |  └──/app.yaml`

I assume if it supports Go 1.11 we could also use [Modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) for versioning but I haven't looked into that yet.

Answer (score 0):

The `context` package will be inside `$GOROOT` ( not in `vendor` directory ). Probably your Go Appengine SDK is old and does not support Go 1.8.

Update your SDK to the latest version. The `$GOROOT` should be like `/path/to/somewhere/goroot-1.8`

Comment: This happens when I run it on Cloud Shell directly by using the App Engine online console. There are using go1.10.

Comment: Are you trying to run local server for debugging? or deploying your application? When debugging, consider to use your own PC. When deploying try to run `goapp deploy app/app.yaml`.

Comment: `goapp version` on Cloud Shell returns `go version go1.6.3 (appengine-1.9.48) linux/amd64`. This version does not support Go 1.8.

Comment: Thanks N.F. for spotting that up. I'm currently using the other approach that I described in my response to this thread.